# Neo4j IO Usage 100%

Tags: neo4j

I had a Windows Neo4j DB with 100 million nodes and 2 hundred million relationships(200 relationships per node). When I try to query the below node A and node X with at most 3 paths to get each other (By Neo4j browser):

MATCH p=((a:Person{Name:“Num996567”})-[r:Call*…3]->(x:Person{name:“Num280704”}))
RETURN distinct a,p,x;

And Here is the Explain for this query:(Is it expected for the empty Explain Plan TextBox?)

[image]

This query will be in running status for a long time without return any result, So I go back to the System IO Monitor window, the IO for process neo4j is 1.1M/s, but the IO Usage will be touch 100%(attachment) when I fire the query (If I end the query manually, the IO usage will be down to a normal volume), I guess this IO usage issue cause the MATCH query always in running status.

[image]

The node has two attribute ID and Name, ID is a number in 100 million, such as  1625, Name is a String combined by "Num"+ID, such as "Num1625", and I had added the index on these two attributes.

Could you help on this query issue?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Can you add the image from the EXPLAIN for this query to the question ? Also, you're not limiting the number of paths to 3, you're limiting the number of hops to 3 (there may be loads of paths between the two nodes).

Comment: Thank you Tom for your response, I am very new on Neo4j, I had attached the Explain for the query in the initial comments (but seems something going wrong which Explain Plan Text Box is empty, is it expected?).

Comment: For the limitation of 3, Actually I want those paths which the length between  X And A is 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: Can you refresh the browser session and try the EXPLAIN again ? It should show something ...

Comment: Thanks Tom, I had re-try several times to refresh the browser session, but it still doesn't help.